# Send messages between apps on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os, messaging

Can I use the Android Wearable MessageAPI to send messages between apps with different application ids?

Comment: Please try and let us know :) Thanks

Comment: Ah, crap. After reviewing https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi in more detail:
"A message is private to the application that created it and accessible only by that application on other nodes."